# list plugins not working

Tags: grails

I am trying to list the grails plugins but i get the following output:

> C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Test>grails list-plugins |
>   Environment set to development..... [Fatal Error]
>   plugins-list-grailsCentral.xml:564:7: XML document structures must 
>   start and end within the same entity. | Error No plugins found in
>   repository: grailsCentral. This may be because the r epository is
>   behind an HTTP proxy.
>
> Plugins available in the grailsCore repository are listed below:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- dummy               <>               -- hibernate           <1.3.7>          --  Hibernate
>   for Grails tomcat              <1.3.7.2>        --  Apache Tomcat
>   plugin for Grails webflow             <1.3.7>          --  Spring Web
>   Flow Plugin
>
> Plug-ins you currently have installed are listed below:
>   ------------------------------------------------------------- hibernate           2.0.1            --  Hibernate for Grails jquery
>   1.7.1            --  JQuery for Grails resources           1.1.6            --  Resources tomcat              2.0.1            --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails webxml              1.4.1            -- 
>   WebXmlConfig
>
> To find more info about plugin type 'grails plugin-info [NAME]'

Any suggestions how i can fix this?
And i am not behind a HTTP Proxy i am connected to a normal network with a single router.

Comment: I found my problem for some reason my grails plugins is only downloading half way http://pastebin.com/KKVpHXZZ

Comment: I deleted my .grails folder found @ C:\Users\user\.grails and then created a new app and listed plugins and it worked for some silly reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone faced a similar issue and [posted on the mailing list](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/error-downloading-plugins-td3021082.html). You can look at file `~/.grails/<grailsVersion>/plugins-list-grailsCentral.xml` to see what's wrong with your plugin list. Try again in a couple of minutes, the problem should solve from itself.

Comment: Thanks will look at my plugins-list-grailsCentral.xml

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're mixing grails 1.3.7 and grails 2.0.1

Make sure you have the same grails version in both the path, the grails_home variable and/or your IDE.

Comment: I did not download 1.3.7, This is my first time trying grails so i downloaded 2.0.1 and added the paths correctly unless i need to change a setting some where i dont think i am mixing the two